# How do I find the roots of the disconnected subgraphs of a directed graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms

If I have a directed acyclic graph $G(V,E)$, which may consist of several disconnected subgraphs $G_i(V_i,E_i) \subset G(V,E)$, how do I find the root of every subgraph $G_i(V_i,E_i)$?

Comment: Acyclic graphs have *sources* and *sinks*, but *root*? What is this?

Comment: @HEKTO: as I understand it, a _root_ node in a directed graph allows you to reach all of the other nodes in the graph. _Source_ nodes do not have this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the following algorithm:

1. Identify the [weakly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)) components (i.e., the disconnected subgraphs). To do this, you can turn all edges into undirected edges and, then, use a [graph traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) algorithm.
2. For each  component, select the node that has no incoming edges (i.e., the *source* node) as the root. If there is more than one source node, then there is no root in this component.

[image]

Note that this solution assumes the [root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooted_graph) of a directed acyclic graph $G=(V,E)$ to be a node $r$ such that $\forall v \in V-\{r\} \Rightarrow \exists P=[(r, v_1),(v_1,v_2), ...,(v_{n-1},v)]$, where $P$ represents a directed path from $r$ to $v$.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

$V - \{ b\ | \exists a. (a,b) \in E \}$

This is, all the vertices exept those which are the destination of some directed edge